# How to get in TensorBoard accuracy plot when using a keras model with tf.estimator?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, metrics, tensorboard, tensorflow-estimator

I build a model using keras with `TensorFlow 1.12`. After (or during) the training the model, I can see with `Tensorboard` the accuray and loss distribution as a function of the number of epoch.

when using a keras model and transforming it with `model_to_estimator accuracy` and loss are not stored in `events.out.tfevents.xxxxxxxxxx` (used by TensorBoard for visualiztion). I am using `tf.estimator.train()` or `tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate(estimator, train_spec, eval_spec)` and in both cases I only get:

```
dict_keys(['global_step/sec', 'loss_1'])
```

using `tf.estimator.train()` I am expecting loss and accuray in `events.out.tfevents.xxxxxxxxxx` for the training dataset

using `tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate(estimator, train_spec, eval_spec)` I am expecting loss and accuray in `events.out.tfevents.xxxxxxxxxx` for the training dataset abd testing datset.

The info are computed and display in the logfiles:

```
INFO:tensorflow:Done running local_init_op.
INFO:tensorflow:Evaluation [10/100]
INFO:tensorflow:Evaluation [20/100]
INFO:tensorflow:Evaluation [30/100]
INFO:tensorflow:Evaluation [40/100]
INFO:tensorflow:Evaluation [50/100]
INFO:tensorflow:Evaluation [60/100]
INFO:tensorflow:Evaluation [70/100]
INFO:tensorflow:Finished evaluation at 2019-03-16-12:28:05
INFO:tensorflow:Saving dict for global step 1000: accuracy = 0.9766614, global_step = 1000, loss = 0.074898034
INFO:tensorflow:Saving 'checkpoint_path' summary for global step 1000: results/Models/Mnist/tf_1_12/estimator/ckpt/model.ckpt-1000
```

How can I add some metrics when I convert a keras model to an estimator ? If I return directly an estimator, I just need to add `tf.summary.scalar('accuracy', accuracy[1])`. I could't find anything up to know.

when I am using the same keras model and running the fit method, I got in the `events.out.tfevents.xxxxxxxxxx` file:

```
dict_keys(['batch_acc', 'batch_loss', 'epoch_acc', 'epoch_loss', 'epoch_val_acc', 'epoch_val_loss'])
```

I got 6 variables inluding accuracy and loss for the training and test datset. This is what I am expected.

Is this expected ? Without such info in TensorBoard then it is impossible to see if the model is overfitting or not. I am not even sure which info is displayed in the logfile, right ?

Any idea ?

EDIT:
I am now sure this is a Bug/or a feature. I opened a ticket:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/26804

and saw a similar one from August 2018:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/21983

Next steps is to see if this works with Tensorflow 2.0 since here, Keras officialy is the high level API. I builded a model using tf.estimator and keras layers and I could add and see accuray and loss.